# Parallel execution of multiple scenarios

Tags: gatling

What ist the best practice for parallel execution of multiple scenarios? For example 30% Users execute scenario1 and 70% users scenario2.

Is the code below the right way or is it better to have one scenario with contional executions of REST calls?

```
class MySimulation extends Simulation {

  val userIdsData = csv(userIdsCSV).queue



  ...



  val scenario1 = scenario("Scenario 1")

    .feed(userIdsData)

    .get(...)



  val scenario2 = scenario("Scenario 2")

    .feed(userIdsData)

    .get(...)

    .post(...)



  setUp(scenario1.inject(rampUsers(30) over (ramp seconds))

      .protocols(HttpConfig.value(baseURL)),

    scenario2.inject(rampUsers(70) over (ramp seconds))

      .protocols(HttpConfig.value(baseURL))

  )

}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Whatever you are doing is absolutely fine.

The way you are running the setup you will see that the requests are running in parallel.

Comment: Does a scenario composed as: `scenario("Scenario Name").exec(Search.search, Browse.browse, Edit.edit)
` run in parallel ? Or the three components will be executed sequentially ?

Comment: @Sergio Runs in parallel and not in sequence.

Comment: Thanks. It is still a bit confusing when should I use the idiom above for parallel execution, and when should I use instead distinct "users", as in: `setUp(users.inject(atOnceUsers(1), admin.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpConf))` Could you clarify ?

Comment: what about doing one-time POST request before and after scenario -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386159/gatling-exec-outside-scenario-scope-post-requests-are-not-called - I am not getting POST requests at all - how can I even debug

Comment: Could you explain why exactly this runs in parallel?

Answer (score 14):

Gatling will run each item within SetUp in parallel where as each item defined in a scenario will be run [sequentially](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/general/simulation_setup/#injection). As you can see from the link

> The definition of the injection profile of users is done with the
> inject method. This method takes as argument a sequence of injection
> steps that will be processed sequentially.

So your above code will run `scenario01 ramp to 30 over x seconds` and `scenario02 ramp to 70 over y seconds` in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with below code .

```
scenario1.inject(rampConcurrentUsers(0) to (6) during(10),constantConcurrentUsers(6) during(60 seconds)),

scenario2.inject(rampConcurrentUsers(0) to (4) during(10),constantConcurrentUsers(4) during(60 seconds))
```